# Laravel 5: Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: sql, laravel-5

Estoy intentando crear las siguientes dos tablas con Laravel:

```html
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->bigIncrements('id');
   $table->primary('id');
   $table->bigInteger('numPedido')->unsigned();
   $table->string('name', 300);
   $table->string('business', 300)->nullable();
   $table->string('dni', 20);
   $table->string('phone', 20);
   $table->string('address', 300);
   $table->string('cp', 10);
   $table->string('town', 100);
   $table->string('city', 100);
   $table->string('email', 300);
   $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('order_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->bigIncrements('id'); 
   $table->primary('id');
   $table->bigInteger('order_numPedido')->unsigned();
   $table->foreign('order_numPedido')
         ->references('numPedido')
         ->on('orders')
         ->onDelete('cascade');
   $table->string('name', 300);
   $table->string('quantity', 5);
   $table->string('import', 10);
});
```

Pero me genera el siguiente error:

```
General error: 1005 Can't create table `orders` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

No consigo dar con el problema. 
Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es por un conflicto con la llave primaria.

No necesitas agregar las líneas `$table->primary('id');`. Cuando estableces la columna `id` con `$table->bigIncrements('id');` ya se establece como llave primaria.

Puedes ver más información al respecto en la documentación oficial: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#columns

Answer (score 0):

A la hora de crear los migraciones, recuerda que debes crear primero la tabla/modelo a la cual le vas a relacionar.

```
php artisan make:model Order -m 
php artisan make:model Order-item -m
```